# How to invoke multiple AWS Lambda functions on same custom subdomain in different paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Here's my situation. I have 2 AWS lambda functions that I want to use under one subdomain route let's call it api.mywebsite.com. To get it setup I made all the necessary changes to the certificate manager, api gateway, dns records and all that. The subdomain works great with one lambda function. However, when I try to add the second lambda function on API mappings I get errors like cannot get, or "Missing Authentication Token". I cannot get this to work with multiple lambdas.

The following is the setup:

Custom Domains setup:
[image: Custom Domains setup]

production-mywebsite-api setup:
[image: production-mywebsite-api setup]

production-mywebsite-payments-api setup:
[image: production-mywebsite-payments-api setup]

Do you know if it's possible to have one domain working for various lambda functions? Like lets say the domain is api.mywebsite.com but I have 1 lambda that can be reached on api.mywebsite.com/lambda1 and another lambda function that can be reached on api.mywebsite.com/lambda2?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to integrate multiple lambdas into an Api.   AWS even considers it a  [best practice](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/) for larger serverless applications.

Comment: Why don't you just add 2 different resources with appropriate methods to your API gateway? Each of those methods, you can map to different Lambda function...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue that I was having was due to deploying separate lambda functions to separate api getaway configurations. As you can see form my post I had different configurations for both of them. This is like fedonev pointed out a bad practice.

After reading [this article](https://www.serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-multiple-services/) and unifying my lambda functions under one api gateaway configuration on deployment I was able to deploy all of them to the same subdomain.